# xampp not able to run php files

Tags: 12.04, xampp

I have installed Xampp server properly in ubuntu 12.10. also changed permissions of htdocs folder where my php files are stored, but when I run my project these files are not accessed.

I am using xampp for running my android application.

I am connecting xampp to my android application. php files contains database queries. url of these files are stated in my code as 10.0.2.2/file_name. but when i run my code these files are not accessed. same code is running easily in windows but i think may file permission is creating problem in ubuntu. I followed instructions provided by link forums.bizhat.com/linux-freebsd-opensource/… but still querries in php files doesn't run.
can anyone please help.

Sample project link is http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

when I run this project I get "Json parser error".
it is because my code is not able to reach database querries which are written in php files (saved in htdocs of xampp).

same code is running properly in windows but i want it to run in ubuntu. so is there any way to do so ???

How can i make my php files get accessed ??

thanks in advance..

Comment: Please describe what is happening in detail. "Are not accessed" can mean a lot. What do you do, what do you see after you do this, what did you expect to see, did you test plain text/html files, what happened, etc etc. I'm not sure how you expect to get help with limited information like this. Please do some debugging first ;)

Comment: @nanne I am connecting xampp to my android application. php files contains database queries. url of these files are stated in my code as 10.0.2.2/file_name. but when i run my code these files are not accessed. same code is running easily in windows but i think may file permission is creating problem in ubuntu. 
I followed instructions provided by link http://forums.bizhat.com/linux-freebsd-opensource/41058-how-install-xampp-ubuntu-linux-running-normal-user.html  but still querries in php files doesn't run.

Comment: Please add updates to your question to the question body. Also, explain what you mean by "not accessed". what is accessed, does a plain html work, etc etc.

Comment: @nanne not accessed means they doesn't run. i am asking is this because of file permission or something ??

Comment: Please dd more information to the question (not as a comment!). Please explain what does happen (404? a different page?). please explain what happens with non-php files. This is not a forum, this is a Q&A site, so the idea is a complete description in the Q, where A's can be posted.

Comment: @Nanne I get Json parser error. I am using php script for connecting database to android not for creating any website..

Just tell me how can I change permission of xampp so that I can become owner and use xampp easily as used in windows.
I followed instructions in http://forums.bizhat.com/linux-freebsd-opensource/41058-how-install-xampp-ubuntu-linux-running-normal-user.html link but it does'nt worked for me ....

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you follow the instruction in this link [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

Don't install using the LAMP stack method, instead follow the instruction below it where you have to install Apache, PHP and Mysql one by one.

With this, you will pretty much get the general idea how the directories, Mysql services and all other stuff works. Good luck!

Btw, don't forget to remove your XAMP first.

Comment: @AFwcxx- can't you just help me with xampp only ??